# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

I tried to intergrate Dialogflow API in my flutter app ; after I submitted the message I should get a reply from Dialogflow but
I get an error:

> Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The
>   method '[]' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null Tried
>   calling:)

Here is my code(chatbot.dart):

```
class Chatbot extends StatefulWidget {
  Chatbot({
    Key key,
    this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageDialogflowV2 createState() => _HomePageDialogflowV2();
}

class _HomePageDialogflowV2 extends State<Chatbot> {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Send a message"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void response(query) async {
    _textController.clear();
    AuthGoogle authGoogle = await AuthGoogle(
      fileJson: "assets/credentials-assem.json",
    ).build();

    Dialogflow dialogflow = Dialogflow(
      authGoogle: authGoogle,
      language: Language.ENGLISH,
    );
    AIResponse response = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
    ChatMessage message = ChatMessage(
      text: response.getMessage() ??
          CardDialogflow(
            response.getListMessage()[0],
          ).title,
      name: "Bot",
      type: false,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) {
    _textController.clear();
    ChatMessage message = ChatMessage(
      text: text,
      name: "Aseem",
      type: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    response(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ChatBot"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
          itemCount: _messages.length,
        )),
        Divider(height: 1.0),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
          child: _buildTextComposer(),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({
    this.text,
    this.name,
    this.type,
  });

  final String text;
  final String name;
  final bool type;

  List<Widget> otherMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          child: Image.asset("images/bot.png"),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              this.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> myMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(this.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(this.name[0]),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: this.type ? myMessage(context) : otherMessage(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chatbot();
  }
}
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: what did you get for AIResponse?

Comment: That error means your messages array is empty or null.

Comment: thanks for the responce I already got it

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your Dialogflow agent settings.
2. Click on the service account link, this will open your Google project service accounts.
3. Click on your service account --> Add Key --> Create a new key --> JSON and download it.
4. import the JSON file in your project and insert link it with this statement:

   AuthGoogle authGoogle = await AuthGoogle(fileJson: "path-to-your-json-file").build();

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem. `void response(query) async` should be   `Future<void> response(query) async` and the when you call your response function you need to await it so you have to make the function you call response in async.

```
void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textController.clear();
    ChatMessage message = ChatMessage(
      text: text,
      name: "Aseem",
      type: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    await response(text);
  }
```

Give that a try

Comment: what was the issue

Comment: If this was the correct answer you should accept this answer if this wasn't you should post the correct answer and mark it as such this site is all about helping others:)